# Pragmatic URLs vs. recommended URLs

Tags: rest, symfony, symfony-forms

I have Book resources and Author resources. They're connected, because - obviously - an Author wrote a Book, so the GET Book URL is like:

```
GET: /authors/{author_name}/books/{book-title}
```

And this is fine.

I'm puzzled however when it comes to creating (POST) the related resources (in this case, a Book), and can't find anything on the subject in the Symfony area. There are two possibilities:

A REST recommended one:

```
POST: /authors/{author_name}/books/{book_title}
```

A Symfony pragmatic one - just:

```
POST: /books
```

The latter one with additionally sent author and title within the form - which are not needed in the former one.

The usual way how it is done in Symfony is through use of **forms**, which I'm using. When I take the pragmatic approach, everything's fine. All the data, including author and book's title are NOT a part of the URL - everything is in the sent form.

The problem is when I would like to take on the REST recommended approach. Then data are split: some come into form, and some other are part of URL.

Let's assume I wanted to choose that "elaborative" URL with some key data in it. How do I "merge" form data BEFORE the form is validated?

(Note also that I can't require the "title" and the "author" fields *in the form*, though they in fact ARE required when saving the Book to database).

Answer (score -1):

> A REST recommended one:
>
> `POST: /authors/{author_name}/books/{book_title}`

First, I totally disagree that this is the "REST recommended" way. Assuming `book_title` is your resource identifier, the recommend way would be:

`POST: /authors/{author_name}/books`

With `book_title` part of the payload of the request.

Second, I also think it's a big mistake to use `author_name` and `book_title` as identifier. What if they change? What about books and authors with the same name? What if a book as multiple authors?

So to answer your question, you don't have a problem because the "REST recommended" approach *is* the "pragmatic" approach.

Examples:

```
GET /books/{id}
POST /books

GET /authors/{id}
POST /authors
```

Comment: Books or Authors are an examples of a rule. Another example then: POST /book/{id}/chapter - how about this one?

Comment: 1. `POST /chapters` with `book_id` in the payload is perfectly acceptable. 2. If you prefer to emphasis the relationship of the 2 resources then `POST /books/{id}/chapters` works too, but in this case you need to check that the book exists first (and return HTTP 404 if not), and *then* validate the payload for "chapter". It's a two step process. Does it make sense?